# custom BindableProperty of HeightRequest for my custom control in xamarin.forms

Tags: properties, xamarin.forms, bindable

I have created one custom control for wrappanel.but it shows extra space.
so i am trying to create BindableProperty of HeightRequest for control and set it according to content to remove extra space.

this is how i created BindableProperty of HeightRequest

```
    public double HeightRequest { get; set; }

    private static BindableProperty heightTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                     propertyName: "HeightRequest",
                                                     returnType: typeof(double),
                                                     declaringType: typeof(InstallationPhotoWrappanel),
                                                     defaultValue: 100,
                                                     defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                     propertyChanged: heightTextPropertyChanged);

    private static void heightTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (InstallationPhotoWrappanel)bindable;
        control.HeightRequest = Convert.ToDouble(newValue);
    }
```

but it gives me exception

```
exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

what i am doing wrong here.please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom control should already have a `HeightRequest` property. I am assuming you are creating a custom bindable property with name as `HeightText`.

If that is so, there are three issues I can see in the code:

1. `propertyName: "HeightRequest"` should be `propertyName: "HeightText"`
2. To ensure we don't get target property type-mismatch exceptions, change `defaultValue: 100` to `defaultValue: (double)100`
3. And add a `HeightText` property using `GetValue`, and `SetValue`

   ```
   public double HeightText
   {
       get
       {
           return (double)GetValue(HeightTextProperty);
       }
       set
       {
           SetValue(HeightTextProperty, value);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I didn't explicitly cast my default value so it was evaluating to an int. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look below code and try it. Hope, It will help you.

## Code

```
public static readonly BindableProperty HeightRequestProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create<InstallationPhotoWrappanel,double>(i=>i.HeightRequest,100,BindingMode.TwoWay,heightTextPropertyChanged);

public double HeightRequest
{
    get
    {
        return (double)GetValue(HeightRequestProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(HeightRequestProperty, value);
    }
}

static bool heightTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, double value)
{
    var control = (InstallationPhotoWrappanel)bindable;
    control.HeightRequest = value;
    return true;
}
```